# Convert html code into hex

Tags: javascript, data-conversion

I am trying to convert this html code into hex.

for example: `Macy&#39;s` will be converted into `Macy%27s`.

any help appreciated!

Comment: something like `'Macy&#39;s'.replace(/&#(.+?);/g,function(_, $1){
    return '%'+(+$1).toString(16);
});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with func param like

```
'Macy&#39;s'.replace(/&#(.+?);/g,function(_, $1){ 
    return '%'+(+$1).toString(16); //create the new substring (to put in place of the substring received from parameter #1)
}); //"Macy%27s"
```